# KVM/libvirt: NAT forwarding virtual bridge to host bridge

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, libvirt

I currently have a VM setup where only a few 'special' VMs are allowed to have outward facing IP addresses and the rest aren't. All of them are configured with two interfaces attached to a virtual bridge (virbr0) configured via libvirt. This is to make sure they have the proper IPs and hostnames.

I'd like to set up the virtual network to route the traffic on these private networks via the external network so that virbr0 is attached to br0 is attached to eth0. I need this so all of VMs can access our filesystems on NIS.

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my non-special VMs to get any kind of external network access and haven't found any documentation about this specific use case. Here's the relevant bits of my network config:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>0f4f4cc4-685d-4d01-9b14-e9b851b5b750</uuid>
  <forward dev='br0' mode='nat'>
    <interface dev='br0'/>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0' />
  <mac address='52:54:00:84:f2:a4'/>
  <domain name='domain.company.com'/>
  <ip address='10.0.122.1' netmask='255.255.0.0'>
    <dhcp>
      ............
```

I've played around with this a bit but haven't had any luck accessing other machines on our network or even something like google.

Thoughts?